# Vertical align inside div, vertical-align: middle not working

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

Vertical-align: middle; is not working.

```
From css file :
#header {height:150px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;}

<div id="header">
    <img alt="" id="logo" src="images/logo.png" />
</div>
```

I would wrap the logo inside another div if it helps to align it to the center of the wrapper div.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this only by padding, because other two ways line-height and vertical-align can't work on `img`....

Write

```
#logo
{
padding: 20px 0;
}
```

`20px` can be anything as you require.

Comment: ,This worked but I consider this kind of a hack, just don't understand why vertical-alig:middle is not working.

Comment: I am good with css, but still face this things many time, vertical-align dont fulfill our requirement at many places

Comment: @Chuchelo: It's not a hack as there is no such thing as vertical align for this situation because it's only intended for inline elements.  Search SO for `vertical align css` and [you will find thousands of explanations and workarounds](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=vertical+align+css&submit=search).

Answer (score 18):

do this

```
#header {display:table;}
#logo {display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;}
```

[Reference](http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/)

Comment: you need to use CSS hack for that

Comment: This is the best answer! All the other answers are trying to reinvent HTML.

Comment: does not support IE7 though

Comment: However, this changed the alignment of the div compared to block

Answer (score 0):

i like doing this:

```
<div style="relative">
<img alt="" id="logo" src="images/logo.png" style="position: absolute; top:50%; top-margin:-75px"/>
</div>
```

Comment: it's a position:absolute; not a absolute.

Comment: @lnuyasha: Also `style="relative"` should be replaced with `style="position: relative"`, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Another option, although it has its limitations:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
   <div style="height:150px; text-align: center;">
      <img src="/centerme.jpg" style="position: relative; top: 50%; margin-top: -25px;" />
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The negative margin should be half of the image height.  So the following image will center in the above HTML:

[image]

This makes the centering dynamic if you happen to have a div that changes height. It can get a little tricky with the relative positioning though, because the image is taken out of the normal layout flow.

Comment: Shoot, by the time I submitted this I hadn't seen Pedro's response. I wish I could delete my answer easily :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
#logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -75px;
}
```

Common method of doing vertical alignment. With top being 50% and margin-top being negative half the dimension of the parent div.

Comment: Of course parent dive has to be assigned style of `position: relative;`

Answer (score 0):

i dont know why it worked in my case... but by I could see it working by doing following:

```
div {padding-top: 0%;}
```